# PHP search array and return only first value that meets criteria

Tags: php, arrays, date, scandir

I have a directory of files that are labeled `YYYY-MM-DD.jpg`.

Using PHP, I am trying to search through an array of these files and print the filename (without the jpg) of the latest date that is before today.

For example:  Today is 2015-04-14

Files:

- 2015-04-20.jpg <-in the future
- 2015-04-11.jpg <-first file that has a
  date BEFORE today's date
- 2015-04-02.jpg
- 2015-04-01.jpg

I want to return "2015-04-11".

I've been working on this a couple days, trying to piece together things from multiple posts.  So, I've gone through a lot of iterations. But here is one:

```
$scan = scandir($comic_path,1); //go through directory DESC
$last_comic = substr($scan[0],0,10); //substr scan to get just the date

function LastComic(){
    foreach ($scan as $acomic) {
  if ($acomic < $last_comic) {
    echo $acomic . "\n";
  }
  $last_comic = $acomic;
}}
LastComic($last_comic);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Great for you. And whats wrong?

Comment: Function scope. In PHP, variables defined outside of a function aren't available inside of a function. You need to define the variable inside the function or pass it in as an argument. I also see you are passing in `$last_comic` to the function but there are no arguments defined in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your code is in a good way:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$last_comic = substr($scan[0],0,10);
foreach ($scan as $acomic) {
    $only_date = substr($acomic,0,10);
    if ($only_date < $today) {
        $last_comic = $acomic;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: good job, couldn't have done much better myself.  I did not see yours until after I posted mine.

Comment: This worked.  Great!!  Thank you!  I felt like I was close but was running around in circles.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty clean:

```
$scan = scandir($comic_path,1); //go through directory DESC
$last_comic = date('Y-m-d');  // today's date
foreach ($scan as $acomic) {
  if (substr($acomic,0,10) < $last_comic) {
    $last_comic = substr($acomic,0,-4);
    echo "$last_comic\n";
    break;
  }
}
```